# Ext JS: Display dates in UTC regardless of browser timezone

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

What is the best way of forcing dates to display in UTC (and ignore the browser local time) in an Ext JS grid?

My model receives dates in UTC:

```
"2014-06-24T00:00:00+00:00"
```

My grid has a datecolumn:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyGrid', {
    store: MyApp.store.MyStore,
    columns: [
        {
            xtype: 'datecolumn',
            text: 'Date',
            dataIndex: 'date',
            format: 'Y-m-d H:i:sO'
        },
    ]
});
```

The dates are displayed in browser local time, e.g.:

```
2014-06-24 01:00:00+0100
```

But I want to display them in UTC.

So far, the best solution I have found is to import **[moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)** and use it thus:

```
{
    xtype: 'datecolumn',
    text: 'Date',
    dataIndex: 'date',
    renderer: function (value) {
        return moment.utc(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZZ');
    }
}
```

Which has the desired result:

```
2014-06-24 00:00:00+0000
```

Surely there is a cleaner way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see UTC support built-in, so you can for example extend `datecolumn` and use `moment` to render date. Example:

```
Ext.define('Ext.grid.column.UtcDate', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.column.Date',
    alias: ['widget.utcdatecolumn'],
    alternateClassName: 'Ext.grid.UtcDateColumn',

    defaultRenderer: function(value){
        return moment.utc(value).format(this.format);
    }
});
```

Then just use `utcdatecolumn` instead `datecolumn`:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyGrid', {
    store: MyApp.store.MyStore,
    columns: [
        {
            xtype: 'utcdatecolumn',
            text: 'Date',
            dataIndex: 'date',
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZZ'
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Its there in latest ExtJs. 
Make use of `toUTCstring()` or other toUTC xxxx() methods available.

alternatively, can do below:

```
// convert to msec
// add local time zone offset 
// get UTC time in msec

utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
```